# ISPConfig serving wrong site

Tags: server, dns, hosts, ispconfig, ispconfig-3

My website loading from another folder, when I pointed my domain to the ip. I have already added the domain in ISP, and the new folder created with default content, but Apache serving another of my site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you left blank the **ipv4 address field** in the site settings (or maybe it's wrong). Just select the ip of the host, and retry.

If your site loads with http, but not with https, that means your website  is not reachable with SSL (so check that SSL is enabled).

When the webserver receives a request, it will look through the list of sites configured to run on said IP. If it does not find a site matching the domain requested, it will serve the alphanumerical first site it finds, so that why wrong site loaded.